# JavaScript replace all of linebreaks

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in my Javascript application which looks like this

```
 var myMessage = 'Thats the first line<br /> thats the second line<br /> thats the third line.';
```

Now I have tried to replace all `<br />` with `\n` and I have tried this command:

```
var messageFormatted = myMessage.replace('<br />', ' ');
```

but in **messageFormatted** there are still the `<br />`s. My question now would be what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any other HTML in the text that needs to stay?

Comment: To perform a global search and replace, include the g switch in the regular expression. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: `var messageFormatted = myMessage.replace(/<br \/>/g, '\n');`

Comment: it's tricky because often this is not really a place for "regex" or "regex-like" patterns. usually one would be advised to parse the html and then remove the `br` elements.